# Downgrading From High DPI Resolution

Tags: windows-10, resolution, high-dpi

I started using ultrabook Asus Zenbook with QHD (3200x1800) screen. After week I realized that nowadays are still more problems than benefits with High-DPI screen on Windows. Some application ignores scaling to 225% and every time, when I connect external FullHD monitor, I need logout and login again to update scaling.

I decided to downgrade resolution from 3200x1800 to 1600x900 which is enought for me. Problem is that some text becomes blur. I thought that it's good idea to divide resolution by 2, because 1 logical pixel is now exactly 4 physical pixels on screen. What can be a problem that some text is blur?

Answer (score 2):

Using non-native resolution will break subpixel rendering, which is used for rendering fonts on screen. Microsoft calls it ClearType.

Subpixel rendering is a technique that allows for higher-quality edge smoothing by taking into account physical layout of subpixels while rendering. If every single of displayed pixels takes up four physical ones, any assumptions about subpixel layout are invalid. Your pixels actually have 12 subpixels each (4 for every color component), and subpixel rendering assumes there are 3 subpixels (1 for every component). This makes results worse than with simple font smoothing.

You can try to disable ClearType for slightly better results: *Start → Settings → System → Display → Advanced display settings → ClearType text* → uncheck *Turn on ClearType* → *OK*.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people on the internet spread misinformation with regard to divisible resolutions. People will tell you you can run a 4K display at 1080p with no blur since it's a nice number that fits. This is simply not true; if you run an LCD monitor at any non-native resolution, the text will not be as sharp. Apple is ahead of Microsoft when it comes to DPI scaling.

See if this helps with regard to external monitors, maybe you can choose a per-monitor DPI: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528847.aspx

Comment: Your link is for Windows 8.1. The OP is using Windows 10. Also we don't like link answers. Tthe answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer for my similar question.

You can dupe the registry into thinking the native resolution is lower than it really is, thus fixing subpixel rendering.

[Blurry screen when using 1/2 native resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/1026528/blurry-screen-when-using-1-2-native-resolution/1026567#1026567)

I have done this for a year now and have had zero issues. Zero blur either.