# Blurry screen when using 1/2 native resolution

Tags: windows-10, dpi, high-dpi

I have a 3200x1800 13" laptop running windows 10. 
Many legacy apps have terrible DPI scaling and I attempted to avoid this issue by simply setting my resolution to 1600x900. My thought would be that a 1x1 pixel would render as 2x2. Obviously this is not the case.

Objects are still blurry though I would have assumed pixels would have simply doubled and I would have effectively half the PPI.

Can someone explain to me how windows is scaling the images to my display and if there is a way to avoid the pain that is high DPI scaling in windows?

Comment: Though a bit tedious, you can go to the `.exe` of your program, right-click and select **Properties**, under the **Compatibility** tab, check **Disable display scaling on high DPI settings**.

Comment: Ive tried that with mixed results. Some times font is still scaled incorrectly.

Comment: That's exactly what should be expected to happen. You're effectively taking an image and scaling it up to 200%, and that's going to look bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I AM NOT AN EXPERT SO I AM NOT SURE WHAT MY SOLUTION WILL BREAK**

**If I notice negative impact from it I will update this post.**

Evidently Windows subpixle rendering does not work this way for a bunch of reasons.

Once learning this I got to thinking if I could trick windows into thinking the native display resolution was smaller than it really was. 
After some googling I found this regkey for the display. The key after Configuration can change.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\SHP144A0_1E_07DF_CC^308AEBB00B16BB169DBCDF562C399811\00\00
```

Several values corresponded to my native x resolution (3200) and several to my y (1800).
I replaced them all with 1/2 their values, logged in and logged out and noticed it was fixed!

I have no idea what this will break so please use caution and back up your registry.

Comment: Ive been running this solution for almost a year now with no issues.

Comment: Interesting! Are there still no issues? 

Also, do you happen to remember where you got the info which led you down this path? The stuff about "Windows subpixel rendering"? I was also under the impression that if you scale resolution on a high DPI screen by integer values--e.g. make it half the original--that it should look good because it would correspond to the physical pixels in the monitor. For example, if it's a factor of 1/2, then every 2 physical pixels in the monitor would become 1 pixel in the rendered image. So, in theory, it _should_ work well without any further steps...

Comment: I actually have since sold the laptop, but I never had issues. 
I reached this solution after windows had terrible DPI scaling, I assumed using 1/2 the native resolution (1500x900 in this case) would result in no need for scaling, and then found that not to be the case. I googled why and was told about subpixel rendering still being blurry and explaining that as the reason I was still having issues. I then looked to see if there was a way I could trick the OS to push a resolution to the monitor and let it do the work, and thats what led my registry hack. Sorry thats vague, its been 5 years.

Comment: Note that windows could have fixed this natively now. But I have no high DPI monitor to test with.